# dot matrix arduino turn off the intermittent led

Tags: arduino-nano, led, spi, shift-register

I made a dot matrix that contain 10 row and 12 column , total 120 led.

I want to turn on the leds like this picture but when I open ground 1 , 2 and pin 0 , 1 , 2

6 leds light together.what kind of structure should I build?

Sheme :
[image]

I tried row by row like this:

```
 clear_cube();
 regWrite(cube[0][0], HIGH);
 set_array(4);
 //delay(10);

clear_cube();
regWrite(cube[1][0], HIGH);
set_array(3);
//delay(10);

clear_cube();
regWrite(cube[0][0], HIGH);
set_array(2);
//delay(10);                                                                                                                                 When I decrease the delay 5 leds blinking.
```

100  50  10  0 delay   [Youtube](https://youtu.be/726pVOY1ut0)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just turn them on like that.

Instead you have to turn one row on. Then the next row. Then the next. Very fast.

So you first display:

```
O@OO
OOOO
OOOO
```

Then you display

```
OOOO
OO@O
OOOO
```

Then you display

```
OOOO
OOOO
O@OO
```

And you cycle through that very fast.  Usually using a timer to run it all.  The fact that you're using '595s will slow you down and make it harder to update fast enough to look non-flickery.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: I tried but it does not work .I update the code like above @Majenko♦

Comment: That code is completely meaningless.

Comment: No. regWrite turn on the positive and set array turning on the ground.I'm uploading a video 100 50 10 and 0 delay

Comment: That looks like it's working. But like i said, your use of '595s will make it hard to make it non-flickery. You need to refresh *very* fast. Ideally hundreds of times per second, though tens of times per second will be tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

You want to multiplex them by rows or columns. If you do it by columns, then do the following: Set all columns to open circuit. (everything off.)

Set the row value pins for the first column, then
activate the column pin for the first column. The LEDs for the first column light up.

Now delay for a brief period (say 20 ms) and go on to the next column. (Obviously you'd use a loop for this.) Repeat.

You should write your code as a state machine using `millis()` rather than using delay, or you will paint yourself into a corner and you'll write code that totally blocks the machine just to display the LED grid. If you use `millis()` and a sate machine you'll be able to do other things at the same time you loop through the LEDs